# Return statement logic

Tags: python, return

I have this code to check for a palindrome recursively with a helper function.

```
def palindrome(s):
    return is_palindrome(s, 0, len(s) - 1)

def is_palindrome(s, left, right):
    if right <= left:
        return True
    
    else:
        return s[left] == s[right] and is_palindrome(s, left+1, right-1)
    
palindrome("racecar")
```

It works perfectly fine, but what I do not understand is, shouldn't it be returning 4 `True`? Since "racecar" is a palindrome, the else statement and thus the `return` statement and Boolean operator is executed thrice (i.e. "r", "a", "c"), while the `if` statement is executed once due to the lone "e". So, to me, there so be a total of 4 `True`. However, it only produces 1 `True`. Why is this so?

Comment: Each call only has one return.  For all but the outermost one, that return is "absorbed" by the function that did the calling.  Eventually, `is_palindrome` returns True to `palindrome`, which returns True to the outermost call.  They don't accumulate.

Comment: @TimRoberts So technically the return statement is executed multiple times, but eventually overrided by the last one?

Comment: The function returns a boolean (True or False).  The last line of the function, `return s[left] == s[right] and is_palindrome(s, left+1, right-1)`, is a logical AND of two boolean values.  It's logic, not addition.  In Boolean arithmetic, 1 AND 1 = 1.  1 AND 1 AND 1 AND 1 isn't 4, it's 1.

Answer (score -2):

You are not using a loop here. I want you to figure it out, but you need to loop it. Right now, it's checking the two Rs and terminating. Figure a way to loop through each letter. If you can't, drop back here again.

Comment: The script is correct.  This is obviously an exercise to learn about recursive programming, and there is no need for a loop.

Comment: but wouldn't that be iterative? I am trying to figure it out via recursion.